# Как задать пользователя по умолчанию для гостей в Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы гости автоматически ассоциировались с каким-нибудь пользователем из базы данных. Например, сейчас если в контроллере выполнить `$request->user()`, то этот метод вернет `NULL`. Я бы хотел, чтобы вместо NULL вернулся экземпляр модели пользователя. Возможно, это будет экземпляр модели App\User с id == 0. Мне это нужно, потому что я хочу назначить гостю роли и привилегии с помощью модуля https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (Auth::check()) { }// Пользователь аутентифицирован
Однако, вы также можете использовать посредников (middleware) для проверки аутентификации пользователя перед доступом к конкретным роутам / контроллерам.
http://laravel.su/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users

$email, 'password' => $password])) { // Аутентификация прошла успешно return redirect()->intended('dashboard'); } } }

И вот еще

Аутентификация по ID пользователя
Для аутентификации пользователя по его ID вы можете использовать метод loginUsingId. Этот метод принимает ID пользователя аргументом:

Auth::loginUsingId(1);
Аутентификация пользователя на один запрос
Вы также можете использовать метод once для аутентификации пользователя в вашем приложении на один запрос. Ни сессии, ни куки не будут созданы, что может быть использовано для создания stateless API. Метод once работает по тому же принципу, что и attempt:

if (Auth::once($credentials)) { // }

Это все из документации на Laravel.su и laravel.ru

Но лучше читать английскую laravel.com/docs

По первой ссылке все это доступно в более читабельном виде.

По переавторизации:
Когда гость хочет залогинится, используй собственный обработчик. 
В обработке сначала Auth::logout(); , а затем свою авторизацию.